# Slowing Speed with each for loop iteration in matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, serial-communication

I have written a while loop in Matlab that is supposed to send each value in an array from Matlab to arduino at a specified time interval using a tic toc delay in Matlab and then read values and store them in a variable and graph them.

The output of the while-loop slows down with each successive iteration.

I increased the buffersize which helped it a lot, but it still slows down too much. Is there another way to increase the speed to print the values on time. I have included another tic toc and graph to show the execution speed here is the code:

`max = 80;
    min = 40;
    amp = (max-min)/2;
    offset = amp + min;
    btime = 5;
    bpm = 12;
    spb = 60/bpm;
    sapb = spb/.05;
    tosd = sapb*bpm*btime;
    time1 = btime*60;
    x = linspace(0,time1,tosd)';
    x1 = amp*sin(x*(2*pi/20)) + offset;
    pause(1);
    fprintf(handles.UltraM,(['<P' num2str(offset) '>']))
    pause(5);
    y = [];
    i = 1;
    figure(1);
    hold on;
    title('Pressure Data');
    xlabel('Data Number');
    ylabel('Analog Voltage (0-1023)');
    t1 = [];
    figure(2);
    hold on;
    title('Time to execute task');
    xlabel('iteration number');
    ylabel('time taken');
    while (i<=length(x))
        t2 = tic;
        t = tic;
        fprintf(handles.UltraM,(['<P' num2str(x1(i)) '>']));
        %disp((['<P' num2str(x1(i)) '>']));
        y(i) = fscanf(handles.UltraM,'%d');
        figure(1);
        hold on;
        plot(i, y(i), 'b*');
        drawnow;
        hold off;
    while toc(t) < 0.05
        continue
    end
        t1(i) = toc(t2);
        figure(2);
        hold on; 
        plot(i,t1(i),'b*');
        drawnow;
        hold off;
        i = i + 1; 
    end`

Comment: I'm not sure what problem you do see, but you can short your `for` loop to: `for i=1:length(x), disp(['<P' num2str(x1(i)) '>']); pause(.05); end`, and it will save some assignments and will make it more readable. Notice, that after this change you also don't need `d` anymore. Also, I have tried to reproduce this, but I can't see any change in the running time of the for loop (as in my suggestion) across all iterations.

Comment: Just wrote an answer, but realized that it might have been too soon. Since you don't have a growing vector within your loop, it shouldn't increase in run time. In any case, if it helps, you may be able to pre-process the strings before you send them and then each reference to `cellstr` will be `O(1)`.

Comment: I could not reproduce this problem on my machine. I tried to clock it but a part from some random spikes, which is expected is seems as is time is kept just above 0.05 seconds. However, I would like to point out that you have a lot of constants meaning the same or partly the same. This makes it hard to see how these relates. It is for example hard to see that `tosd` actually is independent of `bpm`. To avoid masking behaviours like these you need to be clear about your intents. Either through code or through comments.

Comment: `handles.UltraM` is not defined in your code. Also, it seems that you've opened a duplicate [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38724481/send-values-to-arduino-and-receive-analog-values-to-plot-in-real-time). Just a heads up, this is a big no-no on SO, and ultimately doesn't help solving your question much.

Comment: i left the initialization of the serial port out and the parameters out i didn't want to include a bunch of code that didn't really matter for the problem i'm trying to solve @Alexander F. . I opened that second question before i reformulated this one since they addressed different topics i have since deleted it

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of back and forth I think I know what you're trying to achieve and what stands in your way.

I have edited your code to make it slightly more fast and readable. Most of the time the operations take just slightly above `0.05` seconds, and at several time points it can take about `5` milliseconds longer than expected. Your millage may vary of course. Since I do not have an arduino, I cannot know if there is a bottle neck there. You should also try profiling your code using the builtin Matlab profiler (it's very useful) to see what exactly slows your code down.

The main thing I found to slow your code is that you used the `plot` function to add one point at a time to your figure. Each time you call this function, it creates a new graphics object. After a few hundred of those, things get sluggish. Instead you should simply update the already plotted data and redraw it using `drawnow`.

In short, the solution is this:

1) Initialize you plot with a single point and save the graphics handle for later use:

```
p1 = plot(0,0,'b*');
```

2) Then, inside the loop, once your data arrays have been updated, replace the data in your existing plot with the new arrays.

```
set(p1, 'XData', 1:i, 'YData', y(1:i));
```

3) Redraw the plots to reflect the latest update.

```
drawnow;
```

`drawnow` will eventually slow down your code also since it has to redraw increasingly large plots at every iteration. To make things work faster, you might want to refresh your plot after a longer interval. For example, the following will refresh every 10 iterations:

```
if rem(i,10) == 0
    drawnow;
end
```

Full code below. Let me know if you have any more issues.

```
max = 80;
min = 40;
amp = (max-min)/2;
offset = amp + min;
btime = 5;
bpm = 12;
spb = 60/bpm;
sapb = spb/.05;
tosd = sapb*bpm*btime;
time1 = btime*60;
x = linspace(0,time1,tosd)';
x1 = amp*sin(x*(2*pi/20)) + offset;
pause(1);
%fprintf(handles.UltraM,(['<P' num2str(offset) '>']))
disp(['<P' num2str(offset) '>']); % replacing with disp (I don't have an arduino)
pause(5);
%y = []; % unnecessary here, preallocated before loop
figure(1); 
p1 = plot(0,0,'b*'); % plotting one dot to create an object, data will be overwritten
hold on;
title('Pressure Data');
xlabel('Data Number');
ylabel('Analog Voltage (0-1023)');
%t1 = []; % unnecessary here, preallocated before loop
figure(2);
p2 = plot(0,0,'b*'); % plotting one dot to create an object, data will be overwritten
hold on;
title('Time to execute task');
xlabel('iteration number');
ylabel('time taken');

% preallocate t1 and y arrays for faster operation
t1 = zeros(size(x));
y  = zeros(size(x));
i = 1; % moved closer to loop beginning for better readability
while i <= length(x) % parentheses unnecessary in Matlab
    t2 = tic;
    t = tic;
    %fprintf(handles.UltraM,(['<P' num2str(x1(i)) '>']));
    disp((['<P' num2str(x1(i)) '>'])); % replacing with disp (I don't have an arduino)
    %y(i) = fscanf(handles.UltraM,'%d');
    y(i) = randn; % replacing with random number (I don't have an arduino)
    %figure(1); % unnecessary
    %hold on; % unnecessary
    %plot(i, y(i), 'b*');
    % replacing the above with a slightly faster version
    set(p1, 'XData', 1:i, 'YData', y(1:i));
    %drawnow; % first one is annecessary
    %hold off; % unnecessary
    while toc(t) < 0.05
        continue
    end
    t1(i) = toc(t2);
    %figure(2); % unnecessary
    %hold on; % unnecessary
    %plot(i,t1(i),'b*');
    % replacing the above with a slightly faster version
    set(p2, 'XData', 1:i, 'YData', t1(1:i));
    if rem(i,10) == 0 % refreshing every 10 iterations
        drawnow; 
    end
    %hold off; % unnecessary
    i = i + 1;
end
```

**ANSWER TO PREVIOUS VERSION OF QUESTION**

You can vectorize your loop by replacing it entirely with the following two statements:

```
% vectorizing num-to-string conversion
y4 = cellstr(strcat('<P',num2str(x1), '>'));

% deleting all spaces
y4 = cellfun(@(u) u(~isspace(u)), y4, 'UniformOutput', false)
```

This small adjustment makes your program run `x4` faster on my PC.

Displaying/printing the results could also be done using the `cellfun` iterator: `cellfun(@disp, y4)`

Comment: The problem is i need to send over the values one at a time so index 1 index 2 etc and i need to send them over at some uniform interval i tried modifying the code you gave so that it would do that but still had slow performance it took about 1 minute longer than it should've when i was trying to run it for a 5 minute time period

Comment: @emg184, I am quite confused regarding what you mean by "send the values". Also, do the values need to be generated on the fly or can they be pre-processed like I suggested? You can still have a loop to print the values one at a time after the strings are generated. Generating takes less than a second on my not so hot laptop. Have you tried profiling your code to see what took the most time during run-time? If it is the `disp` function, you can try using `fprintf` instead which should be slightly faster. Finally, why do you `pause(0.5)`?

Comment: @emg184, if your goal is to print one string every `0.05` seconds, using `pause` will not be accurate. Instead you should use the following (assuming, you preprocessed the strings as I suggested): 

    `for i=1:d,
        t = tic;
        fprintf('%s\n', y4{i}),
        while toc(t) < 0.05, 
            continue;
        end,
    end`. Sorry for the one-liner, comments don't allow for indents. If this is what you need I will write it in my answer. In this case, you won't even need to preprocess.

Comment: thank you for your response sorry for the wait to get back to you i was away for a little. I did what you said and it is performing better however what i am trying to do is send the values to an arduino with fprintf and simultaneously read data coming in from the arduino with fscanf and then plot it in real time i've gotten the printing the values part taken care of however and i can read the values but i can't seem to store them in an array to plot later. I can graph in real time but when i graph in real time it doesnt allow me to read the data correctly.

Comment: @emg184, reading input is a whole new issue you have not mentioned in your question or in the example code. Perhaps you should reformulate the question to fit what you're trying to achieve and under which constraints.

Comment: i will reformulate now